# Purpose of using a=2 in Pollard p-1 factorization method

Tags: factoring

The [Pollard p-1 factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) method states if $\gcd(2^{B!}-1,n)=p$ where $p>1$ and $B$ bounds the prime factors of $p$, then $p$ is a prime factor of $n$.

- Shouldn't it be $\gcd(a^{B!}-1,n)$ for any arbitrary $a$?
- Why are we choosing $a=2$? Is it because it is computationally cheaper to compute powers of $2$? ( left shift ).
- Moreover, should $B$ be an upper bound of the prime factor of $p-1$ or an upper bound of the prime factor of $p-1$ along with its powers?
  [image: pollard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Pollard's $p-1$ we can use almost any $a$ in $\gcd(a^{B!}-1,n)$.

Yes, there can be a small advantage in initializing the question's algorithm with $a=2$ because it is computationally cheaper to compute powers of $2$, but that is essentially not used in the proposed pseudo-code.

The rest of this answer explains how that could be. I won't touch the question of choosing the bound $B$, since when we are at optimizing Pollard's $p-1$ we actually need to consider and optimize the choice of two bounds $B_1$ and $B_2$, and compute $\gcd(a-1,n)$ more often than shown, and make a few other changes; that's easily the subject of a PhD.

---

When computing $x\gets a^k\bmod n$ for $k>0$, the left-to-right binary exponentiation method goes:

- $x\gets a$
- for each bit in $k$ from second most significant to least significant

  - if the current bit in $k$ is $0$ then

    - $x \gets x\times x\bmod n$
  - else

    - $x \gets x\times x\times a\bmod n$

When we specialize to $a=2$ and consider large $k$, we can improve the above algorithm. Let $|n|$ be the number of bits in $n$, that is $|n|\underset{\text{def}}=\left\lceil\log_2(n+1)\right\rceil$. We can replace the first $u\approx2\,|n|$ iterations in the algorithm by changing the first step to $x$ to $x\gets (1\ll u)\bmod n$. And, independently, we can replace the last step by $x\gets((x\times x)\ll1)\bmod n$.

Problem is, the way the question's algorithm 9.5 is stated, it only uses $a=2$ for the very first step. Thus in order to get any saving by the method above, we need to change the algorithm slightly. The idea is to choose a bound $B_0\le B$ such that $k=B_0!$ is manageably large, and in the question's algorithm replace the initialization steps for $a$ and $e$ by: $a\gets 2^k\bmod n$ computed by our improved modular exponentiation algorithm, and $e\gets B_0+1$.

That only gives a moderate time saving, and the law of diminishing returns strikes as $B_0$ grows.

Answer (score 0):

> - Shouldn't it be $\gcd(a^{B!}-1,n)$ for any arbitrary $a$.

Yes, and your code tries calculates it in the while loop. **Note**: normally

$$M = \prod_{\text{primes}~q \le B} q^{ \lfloor \log_q{B} \rfloor }$$ only primes which are less then or equal to $B$ constitute to $M$. The pseudocode in your slide includes all numbers $<B$ which is not correct, it must be prime less or equal to $B$.

> - Why are we choosing $a=2$? is it because it is computationally cheaper to compute powers of $2$? ( left shift ).

We want a random integer $a$ that is co-prime to $n$, i.e $\gcd(a,n)=1$. If 2 is possible choice as in RSA modulus - $n$ is a product of two odd primes, it will be easy to calculate $\gcd(2^{B!}-1,n)$

> - moreover, should $B$, be an upper bound of prime factor of $p-1$ or upper bound of prime factor of $p-1$ along with its powers?

$B$ is a [smooth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number), and in the beginning, you select any smoothness bound for $B$. From [Wikipedia code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm#Algorithm_and_running_time);

> 1. select a smoothness bound B
> 2. define $M = \prod_{\text{primes}~q \le B} q^{ \lfloor \log_q{B} \rfloor }$
> 3. randomly pick a coprime to $n$ (note: we can actually fix $a$, e.g. if $n$ is odd, then we can always select $a = 2$, random selection here is not imperative)
> 4. compute $g = \gcd(a^M − 1, n)$ (note: exponentiation can be done modulo $n$)
> 5. if $1 < g < n$ then return $g$
> 6. if $g = 1$ then select a larger $B$ and go to step 2 or return failure
> 7. if $g = n$ then select a smaller $B$ and go to step 2 or return failure

So the algorithm in sense an adaptive algorithm. In a failure either you can stop or adjust the smoothness bound.